# How to perform the most basic gate-level operations in a computer?

Tags: c, assembly, executable, machine-code

How can I use my hardware directly to perform an operation at the level of bits in my computer without a programming language (and if possible even without the help of the kernel)?

For example, a code in C maybe

```c
unsigned char a = 0;
unsigned char b = 1;
unsigned char c = a|b;
```

I want to do it (request 3 bytes of memory and modify those bytes) directly with my computer hardware and without using any programming language (i.e. I want to write the machine code myself). If possible, even without the help of kernel. How to do it and where to learn about these?

I am currently using Ubuntu 18, kernel 5.4.0-52-generic. I have intel 8th gen core i5 laptop. Let me know if I need to be more specific about my system specs.

Comment: From whom do you want to _request 3 bytes of memory_ if _without the help of the kernel_?

Comment: if you mean x86-64, `or al, dl` will assemble to 2 bytes of machine code that does an OR on those two registers.  You can load registers from memory ahead of that with some values, if you want.  The CPU hardware itself directly fetches, decodes, and executes instructions (e.g. https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/) from DRAM.  The OS just has to set up the page tables to point virtual addresses at physical pages of data / code.  Is that what you mean?  If so, https://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf is a free book on asm.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, and maybe http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ would be relevant.

Comment: If you want to do something without a programming language, then your question is per definition off-topic.

Comment: What you are talking about is electrical engineering (using logic gates), which you would have to build. Your best bet is to start with a logic simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to of course have the documentation for the processor that defines the instruction set including the machine code.

Next you would write something that is not dead code:

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a|b);
}
```

Intentionally not using x86

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1800001    orr r0, r0, r1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Then you can examine that machine code relevant to the documentation and understand the encoding of these instructions.

That is all quite trivial.

The biggest issue is how do you plan to run this code?  You say without the kernel that means no operating system that means bare-metal which means you have to boot the processor, that takes detailed processor and system (chip/motherboard/media/etc) information.  It is obviously possible as your computer boots and runs or your microcontroller (significantly better choice for this kind of education, avoiding x86 as a first ISA is also a good choice).  Or even better an emulator/simulator because you have better visibility and it is un-brickable, where hardware is not hard to brick and sometimes not hard to let smoke out with bad software.

Based on your question, you need to crawl before you walk, and walk before you run.  Start with simple functions as shown, you can with certain tools (gnu is your friend but also enemy as it takes time to master, but it is very feature rich) write using machine code and feed it to an assembler

```
.globl fun
fun:
    .inst 0xe1800001
    .inst 0xe12fff1e

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1800001    orr r0, r0, r1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

If you don't want to use an assembler and want to create the binary file yourself then you have to read up on the file format, many are published, a somewhat trivial task even/especially if you write a tool from scratch to do it and not rely on libraries, but it depends on you and the file format.  Not sure how many tangents and research projects you are really interested in.  They all have value but what is it you really want to learn and/or what is the priority of your desires.

You are looking at potentially months to years of work depending on what you are really after.  As hard as it is to deal with the best path to this is to use the tools and sandboxes available first then replace them later as desired rather than write everything from scratch up front without any help from any existing tools.

You want to build a better hammer you start with using the hammers that exist, decide what you do and don't like then make your own.  You don't just go off without ever using one and try to create one and expect any kind of success.  Or success within any kind of reasonable schedule.

A big problem with doing everything from scratch is that you need to get the bytes into a flash or ram or some media so that the processor can fetch and run them.  This you likely cannot do without some tools, a fully working computer with an operating system where you take your raw bytes, some hardware tools that are capable of programming a flash and using all of that to program your raw bits into that flash.  Now some flashes you can probably use switches (have to solve the bouncing problem) like on the front of an old DEC or something and toggle your way through the protocol used to program the device and thus only needing pencil/pen and paper and the switches and wiring as the tools.

You are far better off with an instruction set simulator and depending on the file formats it supports, rolling your own binary creation tool or using an assembler or something similar to make the file to feed the sim.  Or even better just make your own simulator you learn the instruction set better than most seasoned professionals that way...and then of course you can create your own binary creation tool to match.  You will fail most likely if you have not taking an existing instruction set and set of tools and learned to program at the assembly/machine language level, see how it works, see the instructions used/generated, and with the documentation see the encoding, etc.

Most new instruction sets the software folks have direct access to the silicon folks (walk down the hall to the office of the person, or call them on the phone) and can ask questions about the encoding of an instruction.  Since you cannot do that, you have to ask existing, debugged, tools instead, so as I started way above, ask the compiler, ask the assembler.  Then disassemble it then assume the assembler produced the right instruction and compare that to the processor documentation (understanding that both the tools and the documentation can have bugs so you have to work through that).

Comment: understand of course that you cannot get access to the gates themselves directly, you have to build chips to do that, all this does is give you the ability to create and execute machine code, for which there can be up to millions of gates involved depending on how you count them.